# Mongodb 3.0 "writes is not an empty list" error

Tags: mongodb

Does anybody have already experimented the following error message?

> state should be: writes is not an empty list

Found when I was trying to write documents within the my dev mongodb

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add the code and document that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 22):

You don' t provide a lot of info... but if I were to guess, you are doing a bulk write using a list of UpdateOneModels or InsertOneModels. But the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: writes is not an empty list

Ensure you null check and check the size of list is greater than 0 before writing it to Mongo DB.

Something like

if(list != null && list.size() > 0){
`enter code here`
}